# How to Fix Playback ID Error when using Youtube API to display videos on a webserver?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The Youtube player loads correctly, but the videos display a playback error when hitting play, and thumbnails do not load either. Could someone point out what I might be doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var API_KEY = ""; // Did not include API here but I have it included it my code
    var search = "soccer";
    var video = '';

    videoSearch(API_KEY, search);

    function videoSearch(API_KEY, search){

      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + API_KEY
        + "&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=12&q=" + search, function(data){
          console.log(data);
          data.items.forEach(item => {
            video = `
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$(item.id.videoId)" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            `
            $("#videos").append(video);
          });
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you create JSFiddle with your code? and Explain problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your colons with braces.

`e.g. $(item.id.videoId) to ${item.id.videoId}`